# go command not working if I switch to super user in zsh shell

Tags: shell, zsh, kali-linux, golang

[image: click and see the image to understand my question]

go command not working if I switch to super user in zsh shell ..i even updated the zshrc file ...anyone who knows solution to problem please explain in detail..I'm new to linux

Comment: Why would you ever want to run `go` as root? The root user has a separate shell with separate shell initialization files. Setting `PATH` for your ordinary user will not update the path for the root user. Did you fix the path for root too?

Comment: Please [edit] your question and show all code and output as text in your question, formatted as code blocks. You are using Kali Linux, which is a specialized distribution intended to be used by experts, but your question is merely beginner level. It might be easier to use a Linux distribution which is intended for general use and install `go` from your distribution's package repository.

Comment: @Kusalananda `go get -u github.com/xxxxx/xxxxx`   &   `cd $GOPATH/src/github.com/xxxxx/xxxxxx/` If I want to use th `cd` command I want to be a root user then it works,otherwise it is not working..so what is the solution ..how do I solve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Use `sudo -E` to pass your `PATH` environment variable to your `root` session.

The root user does not know about your updated `PATH` variable, which your standard user account has adjusted in your shell configuration. If you use `-E` with `sudo` it will pass the environment variables to sudo.

Comment: If I use this ```sudo -e PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin/:$GOPATH/bin``` command I get an error saying ```sudo: you may not specify environment variables in edit mode```

Comment: `PATH=$PATH:$GOROOT/bin/:$GOPATH/bin sudo -E` its case sensitive